# Can I use Minimal Ubuntu with Hyper-V?

Tags: 18.04

I am running a bunch of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server VMs on Hyper-V. Now I am wondering whether I can switch to [Minimal Ubuntu](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/07/09/minimal-ubuntu-released) in order to conserve memory and disk space.
Or is there a "minimize" tool similar to the "unminimize" of Minimal?

Thanks, Joachim